# Mysql query to search posts with title, content and tag

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, regexp-like

Requirement

- The query result's order should be like this:
  result by title > result by content > result by tag
- Each result should be in the latest order.

I want to make it in one query.
How to make an efficient query?

The followings are querys that i made with REGEXP and FULLTEXT.

REGEXP

```
(SELECT * FROM board
    WHERE
        title rlike 'first' AND title rlike 'second'
    ORDER BY board_id DESC LIMIT 1000)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM board
    WHERE
        content rlike 'first' AND content rlike 'second'
    ORDER BY board_id DESC LIMIT 1000)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM board
    WHERE
        tag rlike 'first' AND tag rlike 'second'
    ORDER BY board_id DESC LIMIT 1000)
LIMIT 1000;
```

FULLTEXT

```
(SELECT * FROM board
    WHERE
        match(title) AGAINST('+"first" +"second"' in boolean mode)
    ORDER BY board_id DESC LIMIT 1000)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM board
    WHERE
        match(content) AGAINST('+"first" +"second"' in boolean mode)
    ORDER BY board_id DESC LIMIT 1000)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM board
    WHERE
        match(tag) AGAINST('+"first" +"second"' in boolean mode)
    ORDER BY board_id DESC LIMIT 1000)
LIMIT 1000;
```

As i now, REGEXP doesn't use index but it is faster than fulltext.
I don't understand why it happens too.

---

CREATE STATEMENT

```
CREATE TABLE `board` (
  `board_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` int NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `likes` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hits` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modify_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`board_id`),
  KEY `popular` (`create_date`,`likes`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fttitle` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ftcontent` (`content`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fttag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=60027 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Please add the CREATE statement for the `board` table and the EXPLAIN output for each of the above queries. What is the expected row count for this table? 10s, 100s, 1000s or 1,000,000s rows? I assume the `board_id` is the PK for the `board` table which would mean your GROUP BY clauses are unnecessary.

Comment: @nnichols I added the create statement and I tested it with around 60000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp and Union won't be in any particular order.

In most formulations, it would be better to fetch the ids in the unions first, then JOIN to get the rest of the columns from the few rows that result.

Be aware that `UNION` means `UNION DISTINCT` and has a dedupping pass.  (This is probably what you want, even though it is slower than `UNION ALL`.)

Most of the `ORDER BY` you have shown are useless -- they will do nothing, except (maybe) waste time.  `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` need to be paired up for each subquery.  And then again after doing the `UNION`.  A related topic:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or

nnichols's answer fails to dedup.  That can be remedied by an extra (outer) Select that Groups the answers and picks `MIN(col_sort)` with `GROUP BY id` before doing the order by.

**More**

```
SELECT c.*
    FROM (
        SELECT id, MIN(col_sort) AS col_sort2
            FROM (
                SELECT id, 1 AS col_sort
                    FROM ... 
                    WHERE MATCH ...
                    LIMIT 100
                UNION ALL
                SELECT id, 2 AS col_sort
                    FROM ... 
                    WHERE MATCH ...
                    LIMIT 100
                UNION ALL
                SELECT id, 3 AS col_sort
                    FROM ... 
                    WHERE MATCH ...
                    LIMIT 100
                 ) AS a
            GROUP BY id 
         ) AS b
    JOIN board AS c  USING(id)
    ORDER BY b.col_sort2
    LIMIT 100;
```

Don't use a huge number like 1000 for the LIMIT.  It does get rather messy to maintain the 'relevance' through the queries.

Comment: Could you type the query example?

Comment: Also in my querys, could you let me know why REGEXP is faster than FULLTEXT?

Comment: @Jacob - I mad a stab at the query.  `FULLTEXT` is an "inverted" index -- given a "word" it has a list of the rows that have that word.  `REGEXP` must scan each row, hence much slower.

Comment: I mean REGEXP is faster than FULLTEXT in my queries.
REGEXP takes 0.21340025 seconds but FULLTEXT takes 0.68861400 seconds with 60000 rows.
In theory, FULLTEXT should be faster but it is not. I want to know why.

Comment: I tested your query but it takes 0.48452500 seconds.

Comment: @RickJames I am a little confused by your suggestion that `title rlike 'first' AND title rlike 'second'` and `title rlike 'first|second'` are equivalent. The latter uses the alternation operator which means it would match `'first' OR 'second'`, does it not?

Comment: @nnichols - Doh! -- You are correct; thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @Jacob - Were "first" and "second" common words in any of those columns?  Suggest you investigate further by doing `SELECT  COUNT(*)... MATCH ...` for each table.  It would be interesting to see both the counts and the times for each of the 3.

Comment: @RickJames - I did the test with the same condition. "first" and "second" are just examples. As you want, I checked each sql's count and duration.
title: 49876, 0.162 seconds
content: 49876, 0.151 seconds
tag: 49876, 0.658 seconds

Comment: 150K rows in 1 second.  Not bad.  49876=49876=49876; very suspicious.

Comment: @RickJames, I figured it out. It is because I inserted the same texts in the table. The index was useless haha. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing FULLTEXT query suggests individual fulltext indices on the three text based columns.  On this basis I would probably start with -

```
(
    SELECT *, 1 AS col_sort
    FROM board
    WHERE match(title) AGAINST('+"first" +"second"' in boolean mode)
) UNION (
    SELECT *, 2 AS col_sort
    FROM board
    WHERE match(content) AGAINST('+"first" +"second"' in boolean mode)
) UNION (
    SELECT *, 3 AS col_sort
    FROM board
    WHERE match(tag) AGAINST('+"first" +"second"' in boolean mode)
)
ORDER BY col_sort ASC;
```

The performance difference between using RLIKE and FULLTEXT search will depend on the size of the dataset, both column sizes and number of rows.

Comment: I tested your query but it is slower than my query. Maybe it is because of extra column.

Comment: Please add the output from `EXPLAIN` for your two queries, `SHOW INDEX FROM board;` and `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows,
 MIN(LENGTH(title)) AS min_title,
    MAX(LENGTH(title)) AS max_title,
    AVG(LENGTH(title)) AS avg_title,
 MIN(LENGTH(content)) AS min_content,
    MAX(LENGTH(content)) AS max_content,
    AVG(LENGTH(content)) AS avg_content,
 MIN(LENGTH(tag)) AS min_tag,
    MAX(LENGTH(tag)) AS max_tag,
    AVG(LENGTH(tag)) AS avg_tag
FROM board;`  The cardinality and size range will have a significant impact on performance. RickJames' version takes about 0.09 on my 144k rows

Comment: @nnichols - I wonder if your test data came back with a lot fewer rows than the OP's.